# Xamarin: Using fragment in mvvmcross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to use ActionBar in MVVMCross Xamarin Adroid app. I am able to load layout in fragment fine issue is context always pointing to MainView rather than view of the layout. I tried to change the context but getting exception for resource. Error is

Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Code snippet

public class LocationFragment : Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

```
        //View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Location, null);
        View view = inflater.CloneInContext(new LocationView().BaseContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Location, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

One of Android native developer told me I can't change the context as view always drive from MainActivity. If thats right how could I use this with my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBar is deprecated. You should probably use Toolbar, which MvvmCross provides samples for including fragment support: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: Hi Martin is this Tool Bar via MVVM only supported API 20 and above?

Comment: No, if you look at the sample manifest: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml#L3

You will see that it is build for api level 15 and up. If you only would use the ToolBar without some of the higher api levels you could even go down to API level 7.

Comment: Yes somehow I can't even build this project give me few errors :(

Comment: Thanks Martin I managed to started working on Toolbar from the code you sent me above.

Comment: One question. When I am building my project using API Level 16 Visual Studio 2015 and it's a blank project no code yet but all MVVMCross references added. I am getting errors in XML files which are in this folder and automatically created (obj\Debug\resourcecache\440378F780372B6ACD57573F6D8C99C6\res\layout) Any idea? How can I disable this

Comment: Do a clean on your project maybe?

Comment: Hi Martin I have been advised by Xamarin that Android Support Library v7 which is incompatible with the Android 4.1 SDK So I am not sure how would we be able to use if I can't use Android Support Library v7?

Comment: You need to look into the whole Android support library ecosystem. It is compatible with 4.1 but you need to make a difference between compile level and minimum level API.

Comment: I managed to progress and started working on app. I have one more question. I have two tool bar button and have two viemodels what I would like to do when I click on Next button on first Tab control move to second tab I used this code but as we are showing view model here it open in new screen complete fragment Any idea?

return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>());

Comment: Please open a new question for unrelated problems. Describe in detail what the problem is and include some screenshots so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Thanks Martin i posted my next question here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407071/xamarin-mvmcross-tab-navigation-between-view-models