# Xamarin mvmcross tab navigation between view models

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, tabs, mvvmcross

I have two screens which are linked to two tab buttons

1. Name
2. Duration

I would like tab to move to second button when I click Next button. In my view model this is my command for Next Button

Here is my code sample

```
public IMvxCommand NextCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<RecyclerViewModel>());
    }
}
```

> Rather than tab moving to next tab second view is opening in full
>   screen.
>
> Screens attached

First screen

[image: First screen in Tab]

Second screen

[image: Sceond Screen in Tab]

Screen I am seeing

[image: Screen I am seeing when clicking on Next button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this situation i would not use the MvvmCross ViewModel navigation, because to use that you probably have to create a custom presenter.

What you can do is just add a button click in the Activity or Fragment itself and use the following code:

```
var viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
viewPager.SetCurrentItem(1, true);
```

Comment: From view model I am calling a web service to do some check before move to next tab. Is it possible to have Button click above activity code and view model binding working together?

Comment: Sure, you can call your ViewModel from within your view. Just do something like `if(ViewModel.SomeWebServiceCheck)` before the setCurrentItem.

Comment: I added below code in my fragment code for the first view 

var button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                var viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
                viewPager.SetCurrentItem(2, true);
            };

Now as view pager is in main fragment here in above code view pager is NULL

Comment: Thanks Martin I resolved it. I view was not a viewgroup thats why I was getting NULL